# How to use Friendly URLs with PHP and Apache

Tags: php, html, apache

I'm trying to get friendly URLs on my web site so I don't have to call specific file through URL.

Example:

Index page - http://www.website.com

Go to a users profile page - http://www.website.com/username

Could someone please point me in the right direction to find out how this is done.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Apache rewrite engine module.

1. Create file called `.htaccess`
2. Add your rewrite condition in it

   ```
      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
       Options -Indexes     </IfModule>
   ```

And all your requests to server will be forwarded to `index.php` and data from url you can get from Query String

```
$_GET["url"]
```

then you can do what ever you want with it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, would this go in the same directory as the index.php

Comment: I figured it out thank you very much :)

Comment: I find this ridiculous how it got closed for 'cannot be reasonably answered' yet people have managed to answer it easily.

Comment: Some moderators can't figure out so they think it's not constructive or reasonable, don't worry, the most important part is that you find what you are looking for.

Comment: I have edited your question and I have updated title to describe problem, and I have started reopen process.

Comment: Thank you that is a great help

Comment: I now have the problem of not being able to link css files and javascript because it just goes to the index.php.

Comment: if you link it correctly they will always be there so if you have folder like css/main.css than remember to search for file like href="/css/main.css"

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about using URL Rewrite.  Try: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/